# VBA Dictionary add texbox values to a dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I need some help on looping through all my textboxes and adding the values to a dictionary.

Currently, I'm adding all textboxes name's as the key the dictionary.

```
Dim dict as New Dictionary
Dim Week as Class1, wID as String
Dim ctrl as Control
    
For Each ctrl in UserForm1.Controls
If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
   
wID = ctrl.name 
    
IF dict.exists(wID) = TRUE Then
set Week = class1
else
set week = dict(wID)
dict.add wID, Week
End if
    
week.field1 = week.field1 + Application.Username
week.field2 = week.field2 + userform1.combox1.value
week.count = week.count + ctrl.Text 'this part i cant get to work, dont have the option for text or value

Set ReadItems = dict
End if
Next ctrl
```

I want to pass all the textboxes values in to week.count, similar to how all the textboxes names are added to wID (key)

appreciate all help.

Thanks

Comment: What is your custom class `class1`?

Comment: It’s just declaring public values. 

Public field1 as string, Public field2 as string, Public count as long

Comment: Are your textbox fields guaranteed to have whole numbers entered into them?  You'll run into an error if you're trying to add text to a number.  For example: 0+a

Comment: Yeah its guaranteed to have numbers only. On exit of the text boxes it will display a msgbox if its not a number and/or contains a space also it cant be blank

Comment: I believe if you cast the ctrl.text with something like CDec or CInt that will allow you to increment count.

Comment: You are trying to pass an array of distinct values to a variable declared as long?  That variable can only hold a single number, and it would just add the values together.  For example, if textbox1 = 1 and textbox2 = 3, then week.count = 4 instead of {1,3}. Which is your intended behavior? If you want week.count to be a variable holding distinct values, it needs to be something that can do that, like an array

Comment: Though at this point, it's starting to feel like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you actually trying to do?  This seems to need more context.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what I was trying to do.

```
Dim txtname as string, txtvalue as string

txtname = ctrl.name

txtvalue = userform1(txtname).value
```

which then I changed this bit to be:

```
week.count = week.count + txtvalue
```

now for each textbox the value entered is stored in the dictionary in .count